# the minimum cable bandwidth

Tags: sampling

In a sound recording studio 11 microphones are placed at different locations. The data from each microphones are brought to a processing center over wires and are sampled, quantized, binary coded and time-division multiplexed. The multiplexed data are now transmitted to a master recording station. Assuming each signal bandwidth is 20 KHz, the acceptable error in sample amplitude is 0.25% of the peak signal amplitude and a sampling rate of twice the Nyquist rate. Determine the minimum cable bandwidth needed to transmit these data.

Comment: Sounds like homework assignment. What have you done so far?

Comment: Is this the analog or digital kind of bandwidth? For analog you'd also need to know the signal-to-noise ratio of the multiplexed cable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unattempted homework and underspecified.

Answer (score 1):

First we can calculate how many bits we need to represent a single sample with maximum 0.25% error: 100/0.25=400, so we need 400 different quantization values,
to express them in a binary-coded form log_2(400) ~= 8.64 bits are necessary.

If we assume no compression is used (none is mentioned in the text) this means 9 bits. We need to transmit 4*20000 samples per second per mic (the 4 comes from "twice the Nyquist rate" the Nyquist rate is twice the signal bandiwdth of 20kHz). Since there are 11 time-dicision multiplexed mics this means 11*4*20kHz*9bits = 7920000 bits/sec = 7.92 MB/s.

Comment: You should probably write Mbit/s to avoid any possible confusion with megabytes/second.

Comment: @jcaron yes, Megabit/s is what I meant, thanks for clarifying.